# Navigation Drawer Android layout created. How to create onClick actions?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, onclick, navigation-drawer

I'm a complete noob to programming, so thank you for your patience.

In my main activity I have a random quote showing up, then I created a Navigation Drawer (with the help of a youtube tutorial of course). How do I make these "items" react when I click on them? For example, one of them is a glossary, so I will need to write a lot. Should I create an Activity or a Fragment (what's the difference anyway)? And how do I make a click on top of "Glossary" open that View?
Thank you once more :)

Edit: (Here are my relevant codes and layouts)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_quote_of_the_dat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hp.myapp.QuoteOfTheDat"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/randomQuote" android:layout_marginTop="147dp"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and my menu xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/home"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="Home"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/glossary"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_book_black_24dp"
        android:title="Glossary"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/anxiety"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
        android:title="Anxiety"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/physicality"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_pan_tool_black_24dp"
        android:title="Physicality"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/date"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
        android:title="ToBeDefined"/>

</menu>
```

and my java file

```
package com.example.hp.myapp;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuoteOfTheDat extends AppCompatActivity {

        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quote_of_the_dat);



        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_quote_of_the_dat);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Use the Android Studio's template

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set onClickListener on your Navigation View like the following :-

```
yourNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

 @Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
       switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
           // Here in each case statement you need to pass the id of the menu items and then call startActivity(new Intent()) in each case statement.
          case R.id.your_item:
          startActivity(new Intent(currentClass.this, nextActivity.class));
          break;
       }
```

Comment: what's my navigation view?

Comment: You are having your navigation view in your first xml file with id "drawerLayout".
So, you need to first declare this id in java file as





NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);


Thank You!!

Comment: I'm still getting errors :( It says it cannot resolve symbol on "setNavigationItemSelectedListener" and on "onNavigationItemSelectedListener" and on "menuItem". Thank you once more

Comment: Okay, listen check these 4 continuous detailed videos to get your all answers clear.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AS92bq3XxkA

Comment: I used that tutorial to make my drawer, but it doesn't explain how to create activities/fragments and make them work through the drawer :/

Comment: Just make simple classes for your activities as you did so far and call those activities using intent(). 
Thanks.